# How to fix error while sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade

I am getting following error on Ubuntu 12.04 server. Everything on this machine was installed using apt-get install and tried to keep it updated as much as possible. After last update I noticed I can no longer update my machine. This is a critical machine and I am not sure if -f will break anything else. Should I use -f?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f`

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Tried sudo apt-get -f upgrade. It installed new packages, but original error remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command sequence:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Installing just `mysql-server` (without the 5.5 suffix) should work.

Comment: Luckily on this box we are not using mysql. If it was in use, we would have gone through lot of entertainment of restoring data back.

Comment: So just purge the mysql-server* packages, it should restore your system